# Trigonometric + polynomial integral

Tags: integration

I have been thinking for a few days on a tuple of integrals (they arose in an applied case of 2-point functions in Minkowski space that I am studying), but I am not able to get the result I expect. This is one such integral:
$$
\int \frac{\mathrm dk}{2\pi}\frac{(1-k^2)^2}{(k^2+2)^\frac{3}{2}(2k^2+1)}e^{ik\,\Delta z}e^{-i(k^2+2)\,\Delta t}
$$
I will be interested in the limit $\Delta z$ and $\Delta t \to 0$. My guess was to rewrite the exponential with cosine and sine, neglect the sine term for small enough $\Delta z$, $\Delta t$ and expand the cosine with a Taylor function. But this yields a smooth function, and I was expecting the function to be singular at $\Delta z=\Delta t=0$. More precisely, I think this is not valid because ideally I would like to solve the integral for arbitrary $\Delta z$ and $\Delta t$. And I should expect a behaviour of the form $\ln(-\Delta t+ \Delta z)$, diverging at 0 argument. I am also considering some other integrals which involve a different polynomial in the numerator in the fraction in the integrand, and I have the same problem there. Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If $\Delta z$ and $\Delta t$ and $t$ are independent of $k$, and if $k \in\Bbb R$ then on any bounded set of values of $k,$ the integrand $f(k,\Delta z,\Delta t,t$ is continuous and converges uniformly to $f(k,0,0,t$ as $\max )(|\Delta z|, |\Delta t|)\to 0,$ so $\int f\,dk $ converges to $\int f(k,0,0,t)\,dk.$

Comment: which theorem states this?

Comment: I dk what it's called. It's a standard result on uniform limits and integrals.